# Calling class on ButtonClick (Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, aws-sdk

I am new to Android developer. I have 2 different class (MainActivity.java & Upload.java)
I have problem to call Upload.java into Main.Activity.
When I click the button, the app is crashing.
Is there anything that I have done wrong?

MainActivity.java

```js
Button upload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.upload_Btn);

upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Update_Table dbClient = new  Update_Table();

        try {
            dbClient.DynamoDBClient();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.i("sys", "Success");
        }
    }
}
```

Upload.java

```js
public class Update_Table
{
    private String tableName = "Test";
    private AmazonDynamoDBClient client =null;
 
    public void DynamoDBClient() throws IOException
    {
        AWSCredentials cred = new PropertiesCredentials(Update_Table.class
    .getResourceAsStream("AwsCredentials.properties"));
  
        client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(cred);
    }
}
```

LOGCAT:
[image: logcat]

Comment: Can you provide your logcat log with error?

Comment: Yes, sure. I have provided you the logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line in the method like below:-

```
 public class Update_Table
    {
        private String tableName = "Test";
        private AmazonDynamoDBClient client =null;

        public void DynamoDBClient() throws IOException
        {

       //changed the below line 
            AWSCredentials cred = new PropertiesCredentials(ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("src/com.afdal.ftsmetheses/AwsCredentials.properties"));

//OR try this

AWSCredentials cred = new PropertiesCredentials(ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("com.afdal.ftsmetheses/AwsCredentials.properties"));

            client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(cred);

        }


    }
```

Comment: I have tried it but then .getResouceAsStream is not recognized

Comment: "AwsCredentials.properties" is a file where it is resides in you src folder can you check and tell me

Comment: tell the path of the file like for an eg:- src/com.pkgname/egfile.txt

Comment: Yes sure Clairvoyant. the file is in my src folder: src/com.afdal.ftsmetheses/AWSCredentials.properties

Comment: or try this ` AWSCredentials cred = new PropertiesCredentials(ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("com.afdal.ftsmetheses/AwsCredentials.properties"));`

Comment: Tried but then still crashed. I am a bit confused of calling AWS credentials.

Comment: have you tried both ways which i have mentioned??? the error is coming because you are not providing the proper path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79499/discussion-between-batman-and-clairvoyant).